# Misplaced parenthesis in expression

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008-r2

Another pair of eyes to look at this would be great.  I get one of two error messages the more I mess with this.  Either it want's another parenthesis or that it's not a proper use of True/False.  Im just getting a little frustrated looking at it.  Any help would be much appreciated.  It's been a long day.

```
=IIF((Sum(Fields!January.Value, "CDataSet")- Code.DivideBy(Fields!M191.Value, Sum(Fields!Totals.Value, "DataSet2")) < 0 
and (Sum(Fields!January.Value, "CDataSet")- Code.DivideBy(Fields!M191.Value, Sum(Fields!Totals.Value, "DataSet2")))> Sum(Fields!Variance.Value, "CDataSet")),"Red",
IIF((Sum(Fields!January.Value,"CDataSet")- Code.DivideBy(Fields!M191.Value, Sum(Fields!Totals.Value, "DataSet2"))) > 0 
and (Sum(Fields!January.Value, "CDataSet")- Code.DivideBy(Fields!M191.Value, Sum(Fields!Totals.Value, "DataSet2"))) > Sum(Fields!Variance.Value, "CDataSet")), "LimeGreen","Transparent")
```

Comment: What works, what does not work? Did you write unit tests for it? What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I indent the code to the levels of parentheses, I get:

```
=IIF(
  (
    Sum(Fields!January.Value, "CDataSet") - Code.DivideBy(
      Fields!M191.Value, Sum(Fields!Totals.Value, "DataSet2")
    ) < 0 
    and (
      Sum(Fields!January.Value, "CDataSet") - Code.DivideBy(
        Fields!M191.Value, Sum(Fields!Totals.Value, "DataSet2")
      )
    ) > Sum(Fields!ThresholdAging.Value, "CDataSet")
  ),
  "Red",
  IIF(
    (
      Sum(Fields!January.Value,"CDataSet") - Code.DivideBy(
        Fields!M191.Value, Sum(Fields!Totals.Value, "DataSet2")
      )
    ) > 0 
    and (
      Sum(Fields!January.Value, "CDataSet") - Code.DivideBy(
        Fields!M191.Value, Sum(Fields!Totals.Value, "DataSet2")
      )
    ) > Sum(Fields!ThresholdAging.Value, "CDataSet")
  ),
  "LimeGreen",
  "Transparent"
)
```

Conclusion: The inner IIF has only one parameter, and the outer IIF has five. I think that you meant to put the two last strings in the inner IIF:

```
      ...
    ) > Sum(Fields!ThresholdAging.Value, "CDataSet"),
    "LimeGreen",
    "Transparent"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you a million times over.  Seriously, I do this all day but today I'm the only one in the office.